# What is the benefit of using carrier frequency for an amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, instrumentation

I provide the link here:

http://books.google.dk/books?id=wnPNkbJUBxkC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=carrier+frequency+of+an+amplifier&source=bl&ots=mtT6SOFuqJ&sig=1AEAPY4Ke3qHhqqatW2S9kybJes&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YJV9VOqvM4TkaJPQgMAN&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=carrier%20frequency%20of%20an%20amplifier&f=false

Here at page 153, a carrier frequency amplifier explained.
It is explaining how it is modulating amplifying and then demodulating the signal.
What I didn't get is it what is the advantage to use this method rather than simply amplifying the signal.
What use is the carrier frequency here comparing to usual instrumentation amplifiers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in the day when op-amps and instrumentation amplifiers didn't have amazing DC input offset voltage levels and temperature stability, AC excitation of strain gauge bridges were used in conjunction with high-gain AC amplifiers.

Using a high gain AC amp meant you just AC coupled the amp to the bridge and forgot all about DC drift problems.

This solved the problem of dc drift but these days a typical op-amp can be bought that is superior by a mile compared to the middle years of the last century and AC amplifiers are nowhere near as commonplace.

Comment: What was the problem back in the days? I didn't get it. Do you mean that in the old days the DC amplifiers didn't have zero balance and coarse settings?

Comment: They had offset null circuits but temperature stability and drift were a real problem.

Comment: sorry but maybe i have problem with the terminology here thats why it is still blurry. what do you mean by dc drift? do you mean a kind of offset changing during time? and if so why ac amplifiers don't have that?

Comment: AC amplifiers do have DC drift but it's easy to get rid of with a blocking capacitor - the AC (the desired signal) passes cleanly thru whilst that nasty drifting DC gets caught. If you have a DC amp you cannot distinguish between signal and drift. AC amplifier gain drift however can be made extremely drift-free.

Comment: regarding AC amplifier and your remarks: but what if the signal to be amplified is dc as well. it can also get caught then? doesn't it?

Comment: by the way i still couldn't find what does "dc drift" mean in literature. i googled it and no explanation. very few use the term but without explanation. what does it mean? dc drift.

Comment: Input offset voltage is small but present in all opamps. It isn't a fixed value and drifts with temperature and time. Ditto input bias currents. Try checking some opamp data sheets.

Comment: so dc drift means "changing input offset voltage". sorry for making this longer but believe me the biggest problem im encountering is definitions. it is like trying to understand a sentence without really grasping what its words mean. thats why i insisted on picturing "dc drift". thnx i will read about input offset voltage.

Answer (score 1):

As Andy says, such carrier frequency amplifiers (such as "chopper stabilised" amplifiers) eliminate DC offsets, which can be hand trimmed, but may return as temperature changes or the equipment ages.

However, AC techniques like chopper stabilised amplification can also avoid LF noise aka flicker noise.

DC coupled amplifiers do still exhibit increasing noise levels below 10Hz, and laser trimming their offset voltages to amazingly low levels won't help that.

So the value of carrier frequency amprlifiers has been reduced, but not entirely eliminated.

And the [ADA4528](http://www.analog.com/en/precision-op-amps/low-offset-voltage-amplifiers/ada4528-1/products/product.html) linked by Andy is a chopper-stabilised amplifier - with the interesting twist of servoing out the error component instead of simply AC coupling - but nevertheless a simple-to-use, convenient, low power, chopper stabilised amplifier, thus proving the continuing value of the basic technique.

The [Application Note](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/application_notes/AN-1114.pdf) describes how this amplifier eliminates (or rather, re-directs to the 200kHz carrier frequency, where it usually won't matter) the LF noise problem.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the ADA4528 to see how low its flicker noise is!! http://www.analog.com/en/precision-op-amps/low-offset-voltage-amplifiers/ada4528-1/products/product.html

Comment: Moderately noisy, but impressively low power. Thanks for the suggestion!.

Comment: @Andyaka I wonder where the 1/f corner frequency really is typically- maybe 0.1Hz. It's off the curves just like that nasty 200kHz noise spike is off most of curves (to their credit they put one with it on the front page).

Comment: AC and chopper-stablized are two different things.  AC filters out DC, but won't necessarily do anything about input offset voltages of the amp itself.  Chopper-stabilized amps sample the input offsets on the amp, and remove them.  By their nature, Chopper-stabilized amps, being sampling systems, are subject to aliasing.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - I just assumed that as it were so slow, the "auto-balancing" thing just takes it out like drift. I don't think there is a 1/f thing anymore!!

Comment: @Andyaka There's typical 15nV/°C temperature drift, so 0.1°C fluctuations would be 1.5nV "noise", so maybe 0.07Hz corner frequency assuming 5.6nV/sqrt(Hz) white noise?

Comment: Sneaky Andy, Sneaky, I like it! A closer reading of the datasheet (p.20) shows WHY there's no flicker noise in these devices ... and explains the odd noise peak at 200kHz ... it is a chopper amplifier under the hood!

Comment: @BrianDrummond - it's a damn fine piece of work if you ask me. I've just designed it into a multi channel bridge amp and it's doing just fine!!

Comment: @BrianDrummond pls tell me what does "dc drift" mean in literature. what do you understand by this phrase? i googled it and no explanation. very few use the term but without explanation.

Comment: I partially answered that in the first paragraph. If that's not enough, it might make a good new question.