# Op amp noise specifications at DC

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise-spectral-density

One thing I've never quite understood about noise specifications is what happens if your circuit uses DC only -- yet all specifications for noise make reference to a bandwidth.

I have an instrumentation amplifier. Let's say the thing I'm measuring is a DAC, with a spec'd noise level of -149dBm/Hz (== 7.1nV/rtHz if I math'd correctly...), and the instrumentation amp has an input voltage noise of 3.2 nV/rtHz. The gain is set fixed at 5.

My question is, since the DAC is outputting DC voltages, what "bandwidth" do you use if you want to calculate the Vrms noise of the circuit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have DC, then you're not allowed to change it.  Ever.  As soon as you change it, you have a bandwidth that corresponds to the rate that you want to keep up with that change.

Also, your bandwidth may include whatever frequencies you're likely to detect as unwanted noise, even if all you want is a solid reference.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answers regarding bandwidth, there is another consideration : the noise specification shown - at least for the amplifier - is likely to be broadband noise, with some rider in the specification that it is measured at 1kHz or above. Read it more carefully...

There are separate noise considerations at very low frequencies - variously called LF noise, 1/f noise (because its magnitude approximates the inverse of the measurement frequency, i.e. it increases at low frequencies), flicker noise, and "popcorn" noise. These are generally additional to the 3.2nV/rtHz specification, typically apply below 100Hz or even 10Hz, and may be much larger than the above.

Flicker noise or popcorn noise may appear as occasional random variations in DC bias or offset voltages.

To take one example, this [well known opamp](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NE5534-D.PDF) quotes (p4) two separate voltage noise levels, at 1kHz (and above), and at 30Hz, about twice as much. And (p.6) its input noise current density increases with decreasing frequency. Its target market isn't interested in frequencies much lower than 30Hz...

Amplifiers targetting DC may use different techniques ("chopper stabilisation") to move this LF noise to a different part of the spectrum. [This Q&A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141162/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-carrier-frequency-for-an-amplifier/141170#comment285892_141170) linked to the [ADA4528 opamp](http://www.analog.com/en/precision-op-amps/low-offset-voltage-amplifiers/ada4528-1/products/product.html) which uses this technique to give quite impressive LF performance (but there's a huge noise spike around 200kHz!)

Answer (score 1):

Well first off there is always some bandwidth.
You measure once a day or once an hour... or whatever.
And second (but most importantly) if you really care about 
noise then DC is the pits.  There is all sorts of "excess" noise at DC.
(Maybe start with 1/f noise.)