# Measuring <10 pA of photocurrent using transimpedance amplifier

Tags: photodiode, transimpedance, offset

I am working on a project that measures low intensity light.
The photodiode I am using an OSD35-5T. This is a large surface area photodiode. The idea is that the large surface area would absorb/collect more light and hence there is a higher SNR.

To do the measurement, I am using a Texas instruments opamp LMP7701MF (previously I have used an Analog devices opamp LTC2054HV). The photodiode leads are connected directly across the inputs and in zero bias mode.
The output of this transimpedance amplifier (TIA) is connected to another inversion stage (to bring the output to the positive region) - which is then amplified to 6 amplifier stages in parallel. The opamps are all running from dual supplies (+/-5V).

When I try to measure the dark voltage, on the highest gain range, I can see that the output is approx. 8 0mV. this amplifier stage has a gain of 1024 and hence, it is seeing an input voltage of approx. 80 uV.

I know that any bias currents in the TIA will affect the output voltage as it will add an offset voltage. Initially I was using the LTC2054HV opamp (max IB of +/-150 pA).

If the gain of the TIA stage is 1.33 Meg, this would mean that I would see a voltage of approx. 199.5 uV - which after the last amplification stage would read 199.5 mV (please note that I haven't added the input offset voltage to the calculation).

Is there a way to null this offset voltage out? Currently, I am applying a small bias voltage on the second unity gain inversion stage (using a couple of resistors), however, this  is not production friendly. Using a potentiometer to adjust the offset is a no go because the PCB has to operate in high vibration environments. Can anyone suggest a suitable alternative  solution?

[image]

Comment: If you can modulate the light source so the signal is AC, then simple capacitive coupling will block the offset voltage.

Comment: Hi,
thanks for the response.
I cannot modulate the light source as I have no control over  it.

Comment: _"Using a potentiometer to adjust the offset is a no go because the PCB has to operate in high vibration environments"_ Digital solid state potentiometers exists if that may help your situation.

Comment: Covering and uncovering the detector also 'modulates the light source' as far as the detector is concerned.

Comment: If you increase the feedback resistor on the transimpedance you can get more voltage per pA so reduce the effect of the offset voltage (not bias current). There are op-amps with sub-pA bias current.

Comment: Useful search term : chopper stabilised amplifier. There's an impressively low offset amplifier which shifts all the DC problems to 200kHz ... fi that isn't enough BW for you, you can an least use it for the LF end of the spectrum. Let me see ... aah, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141162/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-carrier-frequency-for-an-amplifier/141170#141170

Comment: @winny : Thanks for mentioning this. It is a really good idea as I did try looking into this. Because of the way how the system is configured to run on Bipolar supplies, this means that the offset voltage can go positive or negative and hence would require the digital pot to be operative with negative voltages. 
Or would it be ok if instead of the low value bottom resistor of the voltage divider (connected to GND) I could replace this with a digi pot?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany : The problem with this is that the Lux overload level is set to a certain range and hence the feedback resistor can't go any higher.

Comment: From what I can see with regards to the Opamp is that they are either ultra Low bias currents and High Offsets or vice versa. I couldn't find any with ultra low bias current and low offset (<10uV max)

Comment: Depends on your implementation end the choice of digital potentiometer, but I would suspect you have far more choice if it operates on positive voltages only. There are ways to cheat if you need to "reach down" to negative voltages too. Is only the photocurrent in the pA and you have sufficient Vcc current available?

Comment: @winny
Yes the photo current is the only variable here in picoamperes. the Positivve supply is derived from a Buck converter and the negative is derived from a charge pump inverter. 
they both have approx. 200mA max current rating.
I can see that most digipots go down to just 1k. 
because of the low offset voltages, (uV range) I figured out that using resistors 10Meg and 5 ohm (connected to a 5V rail) would give me 5uV .
Similarly if I needed 100uV, I would have  to use a 200Ohm resistor. It is this low value resistor that needs to be adjusted

Comment: Cheat using some very low drift opamp for the digi pot adjustment?